# ¿ Es posible importar un script sql y dividir las consultas?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Busco crear una base de datos a partir de un evento de un botón, el problema es que de la manera que lo estoy haciendo en el momento, es tomar cada consulta, agregarla de manera manual y ejecutarla, todo bien hasta ahi. El problema es que cada vez que existe un cambio en la base de datos (ya sea en una de sus tablas, o algún tipo de dato que tiene una de ellas `int`, `text` ...etc) tengo que ir y realizar el cambio manual mente cosa que me lleva algo de tiempo dependiendo de la cantidad de cambios que se realicen, dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
$mysql = new MySQL();
$mysql->conectar();
$mysql->ingresoRegistro("CREATE DATABASE MoltranAP_".$idEmpresa."BD");

//Creamos las tablas 

//Table `Electrificadora`

$query1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MoltranAP_".$idEmpresa."BD.Electrificadora (
           `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
           `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
           `estado` int(50) NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '',
           UNIQUE INDEX `nombre` (`nombre` ASC)  COMMENT '')
           ENGINE = InnoDB
           AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
           DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1";

$mysql->ingresoRegistro($query1);
//Table `ArchivoElectrificadora`

$query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  MoltranAP_".$idEmpresa."BD.ArchivoElectrificadora (
           `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           `fechaHora` datetime NOT NULL,
           `fechaArchivo` date NOT NULL,
           `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
           `cantidadRegistros` int(11) NOT NULL,
           `tipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
           `zona` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
           `Electrificadora_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
              KEY `fk_ArchivoElectrificadora_Electrificadora1_idx` (`Electrificadora_id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";

$mysql->ingresoRegistro($query2);
```

`$idEmpresa` es el id de una empresa recién registrada y esta sera el "diferenciador" por decirlo de alguna manera de la base de datos que voy a crear, quedaria algo así `MoltranAP_1BD`.

la cantidad de tablas son al rededor de 30, mi intención es poder importar el script `.sql` y extraer las consultas con esto podría ahorrar tiempo.

¿ Es posible ?

Answer (score 2):

Parece que la única parte dinámica en esas sentencias SQL es el nombre de la base de datos. Una posibilidad entonces sería usar [`USE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html). Lo que hace `USE` es indicarle a MySQL qué base de datos debe usarse por defecto (a partir de ese momento) para las consultas/sentencias que se ejecuten. Por ejemplo si `$idEmpresa` es 1:

```
USE MoltranAP_1BD;
```

Entonces a partir de entonces, todas las sentencias se ejecutarán en la base de datos "MoltranAP_1BD". Lo siguiente sería crear un archivo donde tuvieses todas las consultas sin especificar la base de datos, algo como esto:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Electrificadora (
           `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
           `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
           `estado` int(50) NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '',
           UNIQUE INDEX `nombre` (`nombre` ASC)  COMMENT '')
           ENGINE = InnoDB
           AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
           DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ArchivoElectrificadora (
           `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           `fechaHora` datetime NOT NULL,
           `fechaArchivo` date NOT NULL,
           `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
           `cantidadRegistros` int(11) NOT NULL,
           `tipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
           `zona` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
           `Electrificadora_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
              KEY `fk_ArchivoElectrificadora_Electrificadora1_idx` (`Electrificadora_id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

....
```

Esas sentencias son "genéricas" y se ejecutarán en la base de datos que esté activa en ese momento (que será la que especificaste con `USE`: `"MoltranAP_1BD"`).

Los pasos a seguir serían:

1. Guarda el nombre de la base de datos que estés usando en este momento
2. Crea la nueva base de datos
3. Utiliza `USE` para cambiar a la nueva base de datos
4. Lee y ejecuta el fichero con las 30 sentencias SQL
5. Utiliza `USE` para cambiar a la base de datos original (guardada en el paso 1)

Y si tienes que hacer una actualización la idea sería la misma, pon todos los cambios en un fichero SQL sin indicar la base de datos, crea un bucle que atraviese todas las bases de datos utilizando `USE` y ejecutando el fichero SQL.

Comment: Si, lo unico que siempre cambia es el nombre de la base de datos que lleva el id de la empresa pero la estructura es la misma, voy a probar lo que me dices, gracias!